# Could not get this point of javascript function

Tags: javascript, json

This is the code below, I am confused about this line.
What is this code doing? where does this title ( === title) comes from. 
Plz, can anybody explain me about this?

```
var duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title);

var addNote = (title, body) => {
  var notes = [];
  var note = {
    title,
    body
  }

  try {
    var notesstring = fs.readFileSync('notes-data.json');
    notes = JSON.parse(notesstring);
  } catch (e) {

  }

  console.log(Array.isArray(notes));
  var duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title);
```

Comment: `title` is one of the arguments to the `addNote()` function

Comment: From `title` in `(title, body) => ...`

Comment: It's literally exactly what it says, it filters the "notes" array for the "title" property to match the title variable to find duplicate notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function allow you to create a new array after filtering vaues of an old one

```
var duplicateNote = notes.filter((note) => note.title === title);
```

create an array `duplicateNote` containing entries of `note` where the entry's title is strictly equal to the `title` passed when calling the function.

It is equivalent to :

```
var duplicateNote = []
for (let note of notes) {
    if (note.title === title) {
        duplicateNote.push(note)
    }
}
```